# How to color facet_grid by group in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(sid=letters[1:8], 
               groups=rep(1:4, each=2), 
               blp=abs(rnorm(8, 120, 5)),
               bmi=abs(rnorm(8, 25, 5)),
               gender=rep(c("F", "M"), each=4))

ggplot(df, aes(bmi, blp))+
    geom_point(size=2)+
facet_grid(sid~groups)
```

What I wanted is to color the `sid` by their gender. A desired figure would be:
[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this, but maybe try the workaround [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2096).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the ggplot to a grob, & make the changes there:

```
# convert to grob
gp <- ggplotGrob(p) # where p is the original ggplot object

# assign the first 4 right-side facet strips with blue fill
for(i in 1:4){
  grob.i <- grep("strip-r", gp$layout$name)[i]
  gp$grobs[[grob.i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- "blue"
}
# assign the next 4 right-side facet strips with red fill
for(i in 5:8){
  grob.i <- grep("strip-r", gp$layout$name)[i]
  gp$grobs[[grob.i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$gp$fill <- "red"
}

grid::grid.draw(gp)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5):

#### Data

```
library(ggplot2)
    set.seed(123)
    df<-data.frame(sid=letters[1:8], 
                   groups=rep(1:4, each=2), 
                   blp=abs(rnorm(8, 120, 5)),
                   bmi=abs(rnorm(8, 25, 5)),
                   gender=rep(c("F", "M"), each=4))
```

#### Method 1

```
ggplot(df, aes(bmi, blp, color = gender))+
    geom_point(size=2)+
    facet_grid(sid~groups)
```

[image]

#### edit: Method 2 after clarification in the comments

```
ggplot(df, aes(bmi, blp, color = gender))+
    geom_point(size=2)+
facet_grid(sid~groups)+
    geom_rect(data=subset(df, gender == "F"), 
              aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), 
              fill="red", alpha=0.2)+
    geom_rect(data=subset(df, gender == "M"), 
              aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), 
              fill="blue", alpha=0.2)
```

An even simpler solution is `+ geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill = gender), alpha=0.2)` instead of the two `geom_rect()`s.

[image]

Caveat: As others pointed out, there are ways to do your style of plot, but those methods are quite messy. Above solution is easy and clean, but can obviously only fill facets which contain data.

Comment: In my real case, I have colored the points by another variable. The journal asked us to color the facet labels as I posted. Thanks though.

Comment: @DavidZ I see. There is a simple way to color the frame itself, but it can only cover facets that actually contain any data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is something that needs to be done with a workaround. It's not super difficult though, but you need to manually set colors.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(sid=letters[1:8], 
               groups=rep(1:4, each=2), 
               blp=abs(rnorm(8, 120, 5)),
               bmi=abs(rnorm(8, 25, 5)),
               gender=rep(c("F", "M"), each=4))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(bmi, blp))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  facet_grid(sid~groups)
g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
strip_right <- which(grepl('strip-r', g$layout$name))
fills <- c("blue","blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","red")
k <- 1
for (i in strip_right) {
  j <- which(grepl('rect', g$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$childrenOrder))
  g$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]]$children[[j]]$gp$fill <- fills[k]
  k <- k+1
}
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]